# HTML Header Menu Drop-Down Is Impossible To Click On

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok. I have a header I've designed in HTML - however every time I attempt hover over products, then click on ANY sub menu - I am unable to (they disappear before they are clickable.)

A live example of this can be seen at http://www.bwl-ny.com

Any suggestions?

### Custom.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//INITIALIZES PRETTYPHOTO PLUGIN

    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({theme:'light_square'}); //choose between different styles / dark_rounded / light_rounded / dark_square / light_square / facebook /

//INITIALIZES TWITTER FEED PLUGIN

    $('.twitter-feed').tweet({
        username: 'ABrighterWorld',  //just enter your twitter username
        join_text: 'auto',
        avatar_size: null,
        count: 2, //number of tweets showing
        auto_join_text_default: '',
        loading_text: 'loading latest tweets...' //text displayed while loading tweets
    });

// FLICKR PLUGIN

    $('#flickr-images').append('<ul></ul>');

    $('#flickr-images ul').jflickrfeed({
        limit: 10,
        qstrings: {
            id: 'myflickrID', // enter Flickr ID i.e. 67956216@N02  
            tags: 'tags-here'  // Displays images with selected tags (optional)
        },

        itemTemplate: '<li><a href="{{image_b}}" rel="prettyPhoto" ><img src="{{image_s}}" alt="{{title}}" /></a></li>'

        }, function(data) {
            $('#flickr-images li a').prettyPhoto({theme:'light_square'});
        });


// TEXTBOX ACTIVE

    $('.textbox, #message, #comment').focus(function (){
        $(this).css({borderColor : '#bbb'});
            $(this).blur(function (){
                $(this).css({borderTopColor : '#d1d1d1', borderLeftColor : '#d1d1d1', borderBottomColor : '#e1e1e1', borderRightColor : '#e1e1e1'});
            });
    });



//TAB NAVIGATION

    $('ul.tab-nav').tabs('.tabs > .tab-panels > div', {effect: 'fade'});


// PORTFOLIO HOVER EFFECT - OVERLAY

    $('.gallery-overlay a img').hover(function() {      
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            opacity : '.1'
        }, 300);
            }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({ 
                    opacity : '1' 
                }, 500);
            }); 


// PORTFOLIO FILTER             

    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {
        $(this).css('outline','none');
        $('ul#filter .active-filter').removeClass('active-filter');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active-filter');

        var filterVal = $(this).attr('href').toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');

        if(filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul.gallery-thumbs li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {
            $('ul.gallery-thumbs li').each(function() {
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    }); 


//TOGGLE PANELS

    $('.toggle-content').hide();  //hides the toggled content, if the javascript is disabled the content is visible

    $('.toggle-header a').click(function () {       

        if ($(this).is('.tog-close')) {
            $(this).removeClass('tog-close')
            .addClass('tog-open')
            .closest('.toggle-header')
            .next('.toggle-content')
            .slideToggle(300);
            return false;
        }       
        else {
            $(this).removeClass('tog-open')
            .addClass('tog-close')
            .closest('.toggle-header')
            .next('.toggle-content')
            .slideToggle(300);
            return false;
        }
    }); 


// TOOLTIPS

    $('.social-links li[title]').tooltip({
        effect: 'fade',
        fadeInSpeed: 300,
        fadeOutSpeed: 200,
        opacity: 0.9,
        offset: [-5, 0]     
    }); 


// SOCIAL LINKS

    $(function() {
        $('.social-links li').animate({
            opacity : '.4'  // sets the opacity to 50% to all social link images
        }); 

        $('.social-links li').hover(function() {  
            $(this).stop().animate({ 
                opacity: '1'  // on hover sets the opacity to 100% to all social link images
            });
        }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({ 
                    opacity : '.4'
                });
            });
    });


// SCROLL TOP   

    $('.scroll-top').hover(function() {     
        $(this).stop().animate({ 
            opacity : '1'
        }, 300);
            }, function() {
                $(this).stop().animate({ 
                    opacity : '.6' 
                }, 500);
            }); 

    $('.scroll-top').click(function () {
        $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });


//NAVIGATION DROPDOWN ANIMATION 

    $('#navigation ul').css({display: 'none'}); // Opera Fix

    $("ul#navigation").superfish({
            hoverClass:    'dropdown',          // the class applied to hovered list items 
            pathClass:     'overideThisToUse', // the class you have applied to list items that lead to the current page 
            pathLevels:    1,                  // the number of levels of submenus that remain open or are restored using pathClass 
            delay:         1000,                // the delay in milliseconds that the mouse can remain outside a submenu without it closing 
            animation:     {opacity:'show',height:'show'},     // an object equivalent to first parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method 
            speed:         'fast',           // speed of the animation. Equivalent to second parameter of jQuery’s .animate() method 
            autoArrows:    false,               // if true, arrow mark-up generated automatically = cleaner source code at expense of initialisation performance 
            dropShadows:   false    
    });


// IE Button hover fix  
$(function (){  

    var button = $('.button');

    if ($.browser.msie) {
        $(button).css( {backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"} ).hover(function() {      
            $(this).stop()
                .animate({ 
                    backgroundPositionX: "-20px",
                    backgroundPositionY: "94px"             
                },300);

                }, 
                function() {
                    $(this).stop().animate({ 
                    backgroundPositionX: "-20px",
                    backgroundPositionY: "35px"             
                },300).css({backgroundPosition: "-20px 35px"});
            });
        }       
});


}); //END of jQuery
```

### HTML Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Brighter World Lighting - NY</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!--imports the main css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/style.css" />
    <!--imports prettyPhoto css file-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" />
    <!--imports jquery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <!--imports twitter feed plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
    <!--imports easing plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
    <!--imports prettyPhoto plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
    <!--imports jQuery Tools plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
    <!--imports jQuery superfish plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <!--imports jQuery jflickrfeed plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jflickrfeed.min.js"></script>
    <!--imports jQuery AsyncSlider plugin-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.asyncslider.min.js"></script>
    <!--imports custom javascript code-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // Setup Slider
            $("#async-slider").asyncSlider({
                keyboardNavigate: true,
                easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
                minTime: 600,
                maxTime: 1500,
                autoswitch: 4800,
                centerPrevNextNav: false,
                slidesNav: false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <!--[if IE 7]><link href="css/ie7.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]><link href="css/ie8.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header" class="pattern-1">
        <div id="header-inner">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="img/logo.png" alt="image description" />
                <div id="title">
                    <h1><a href="index.asp"></a></h1>
                    <p></p>
                </div><!-- end title -->
            </div><!-- end logo -->
            <ul id="navigation">
                <li>
                    <a class="active-nav" href="index.asp">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="partnership.html">
                        Energy Partnership Program
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://bwl.ereverseauction.com">
                        Energy Auction
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Affiliates</a>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-23" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-23">
                    <a href="products.html">Products</a>
                    <ul class="sub-menu">
                        <li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-31">
                            <a href="indoor.html">Indoor Lighting</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-34" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-34">
                            <a href="outdoor.html">Outdoor Lighting</a>
                            <ul class="sub-menu">
                                <li id="menu-item-68" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-68"><a href="http://brighterworldlightingllc.com/excelsior-series/">Street Lighting</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li id="menu-item-30" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-30"><a href="http://brighterworldlightingllc.com/outdoor-lighting/">OEM/ODM Support</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="about.asp">About Us</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
            </ul><!-- end navigation -->
```

Comment: Try to make a minimal test case, and put it on jsfiddle. We are not a debugging service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It s becuase of a CSS rule. It is in file style.css line 557, selector of media="screen"
`#navigation ul margin-top: 24px`. This pushes the child UL below the parent, so when you hover the parent, it displays, but as soon as you go down, you move off the parent element and into the top margin of the child, you are not hovering the parent anymore so the child disappears. This top margin, is causing a 'gap' between them, so you have to be really quick to keep the hover event to keep the child open. I would possibly change it to a padding? but you will need to change you background color from the UL to the LI, or potentially add a delay in the hover event to give them time to move down to the child elements, but if they hover in the gap, it could still disappear on them

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple fix.  In your custom.js javascript file you have the following code:

```
  $("ul#navigation").superfish({
    // the class applied to hovered list items 
    hoverClass: 'dropdown',

    // the class you have applied to list items that 
    // lead to the current page 
    pathClass: 'overideThisToUse',

    // the number of levels of submenus that remain 
    // open or are restored using pathClass 
    pathLevels: 1,

    // the delay in milliseconds that the mouse can 
    // remain outside a submenu without it closing 
    delay: 300,

    // an object equivalent to first parameter of 
    // jQuery's .animate() method 
    animation: { opacity: 'show', height: 'show' },

    // speed of the animation. Equivalent to second 
    // parameter of jQuery's .animate() method 
    speed: 'fast',

    // if true, arrow mark-up generated 
    // automatically = cleaner source code at expense of initialisation 
    // performance 
    autoArrows: false,

    dropShadows: false
});
```

To fix your problem all you should have to do is increase the 300 parameter to something like 1000 (1 second), this gives the user time to hover to the navigation sub menu.  Play around with the time until you find something that fits what you want.  Other than that, the site looks great; pm me if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks!! I applied the fix as suggested (I increased it from 300 to 1000) but I still cannot seem to hover over it without it disappearing. (I updated my source above and pushed the changes to the live site - any suggestions?)

Comment: Looks like you got it working, am I correct?  --By the way, you might want to consider preloading your images so they are displayed right when the page loads instead of the content loading and then the images (might be too advanced but still it's a suggestion).